# Docker + MYSQL: Can't access mysql outside the container

Tags: mysql, docker, sqlalchemy

I have 2 docker container which both contain mysql database and I open the port 3305, 3306 for each.
[image]

for the 3306:3306's container I can access it outside the container by

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer, Numeric, String

import os
cwd = os.getcwd()
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, cwd + '/vatic-docker/vatic')
#from models import *

engine = create_engine('mysql://root:1111' '@172.17.0.2:3306/vatic')
Session = sessionmaker (bind = engine)
session = Session()

Base = declarative_base()
```

However I can't access the 3305:3306 container's mysql database by

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:1111' '@172.17.0.3:3306/vatic')
```

which return me the error messages:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError) (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.17.0.3' (111)")
```

What should I do now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The port in the connection string is wrong

So

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:1111' '@172.17.0.3:3306/vatic')
```

should be

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:1111@<host IP>:3305/vatic')
```

since `3305` is the port that you are exposing on the host machine

Specifically if the Docker host machine has an IP address `192.168.2.100` then the connection should be

```
engine = create_engine('mysql://root:1111@192.168.2.100:3305/vatic')
```

format for -p is hostPort:containerPort

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#publish-or-expose-port--p---expose

Comment: I try both. And I thought `0.0.0.0:3305 -->  3306/tcp` means `3306` is the port that i exposing to host machine

Comment: no it means that you are forwarding requests on the host port 3305 to the container port 3306. The connection string also seems to be incorrect. editing the answer.

Comment: I don't get it. `engine = create_engine('mysql://root:1111@172.17.0.3:3305/vatic')` doesn't work for me. I need to modify the container port or?

Comment: One more thing. The IP address `172.17.0.3` seems to be the IP of the docker container. What you need to be using since you are on the host machine or the same network is the IP of the host machine. editing

Comment: 172.17.0.2:3306 WORK FOR ME FOR CONTAINER 1.

Comment: You need to pick between using the container ip address and the default port  `172.17.0.3:3306` or using the host ip and the forwarded port `<host ip>:3305`. I overlooked that you were using the container IP and therefore did not need to use the forwarded port. However, if you will need to run the code from another machine you will need to use the IP of the host and the forwarded port.